# ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader Youtubeplayer fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api

I am Using `SherlockFragmentActivity` as my `AbstractBaseActivity`, on Devices with `API level 10` or lower I get strange exception below is the stack trace from playstore crash reprots

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{somepackage/somepackage.PlayerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at com.toxic.apps.doordarshan.AbstractBaseActivity.initContainerLayout(AbstractBaseActivity.java:133)
at com.toxic.apps.doordarshan.AbstractBaseActivity.setContentView(AbstractBaseActivity.java:108)
at somepackage.PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.java:37)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/somepackage.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
... 19 more
```

My `PlayerActivity` Class

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AbstractBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {


private YouTubePlayerFragment myYouTubePlayerFragment;

@Override
protected void initViewControls() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    VIDEO_ID = getIntent().getStringExtra("EPISODE_ID");

    myYouTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
    myYouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);
}
    ......
}
```

and below is `activity_player`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <fragment  // crash on this line
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[android.app.Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) was only introduced in Android 3.0 (API 11). You need to use [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) and `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you want to support lower than API 11 devices.

Comment: Oh Such an idiot I am, thanks  anyways let me try and will update soon